# Trouble passing data from a .yml file to a method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble passing data from a .yml file to a method to update tables in the db.

My file.yml looks like:

```
[
  { :emp_id: "123"},
  { "emp_acct": [{ :col_id: "22222", :age: "23"}]}
]
```

My file.rb looks like:

```
load_yaml()
update(@database, $x, $y, $z)

def load_yaml
 YAML.load_file("file.yml")
end

def YAML.load( io)
  yp = parser.load( io )
  $y = yp[0]  #I get:  {:emp_id=>"123"}
  $x = yp[1].keys   #I get:   :emp_acct 
  $z = yp[1].values   #I get:  {:col=>"22222", :age=>"23"}
end

def modify(db, table, filter, opt)
  db[table].where(filter).update(opt)
end
```

I get this error:

"Failure/Error: modify(db, table, filter, opt)
  TypeError:
   can't convert Array into String"

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: This is not a valid YAML file

Comment: Why is not valid? That is what I want to get from it. What do you think I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to parse this as [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), because your file does not look like [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). First you should fix the file, since a valid JSON will look like this:

```
[
  { "emp_id": "123"},
  { "emp_acct": [{ "col_id": "22222", "age": "23"}]}
]
```

In YAML the file should look like this:

```
---
  - 
    emp_id: "123"
  - 
    emp_acct: 
      - 
        col_id: "22222"
        age: "23"
```

Comment: How would this be looked like as YAML then? Sorry I am new to yaml.

Comment: @user3673611: See my updated answer on how a valid YAML would look like.